# How to add a field's value via apex code under the existing Account?

Tags: apex

[image]

The code is as shown. I am not understanding where the error is and how to solve. could you please anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at trailheads for a good tour on basics in apex and SOQL queries.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro

In terms of your code, you're missing a couple things.

```
Account ac = [SELECT Id, Phone FROM Account WHERE Name = 'California Wheat Corporation' LIMIT 1];
```

1. SOQL queries follow the format of

```
SELECT [list of api names of fields separated by commas] FROM [object api name] WHERE [filters where you specify api name, operator, and value]
```

You are missing the "FROM" and the name field before the = sign to the value of the name.

2. You're only using Account (as in, a single account value). Therefore, you need to limit your query to only return one value or else it'll throw an error. The other way to do this is to do set the query return to a list of accounts like the following

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'test'];
for(Account ac: accList){
    ac.Name = 'changed name';
}
update accList;
```

If there's no accounts returned, the loop never enters and you don't need to add any checks to confirm it returned values or not.